# Duplicate data from one DB Table to another DB Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to copy Table DOG from DB ANIMAL1 and copy/create the data to Table DOG in DB ANIMAL2.

The Table needs to duplicate all rows (Primary Key) ID as well.

How do I go about that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two servers are on the same network, you could created a "linked server" from e.g. your target server to your source server, and then you could write something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DOG(list of columns)
   SELECT (list of columns)
   FROM SourceServer.ANIMAL2.dbo.DOG
```

If your ID is an `IDENTITY`, you have to turn on IDENTITY_INSERT before the command:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.DOG ON

INSERT INTO dbo.DOG(list of columns)
   SELECT (list of columns)
   FROM SourceServer.ANIMAL2.dbo.DOG

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.DOG OFF
```

and turn it back off after the INSERT command ran.

Comment: +1 - OP should be aware any indexes and other metadata will not be preserved (like FK constraints, PKs, etc).

Answer (score 1):

bcp would work fine I think. clearly if the table already contains rows on the target and you are appending more rows from the source, it will complain if you violate the primary key contraint

you don't say if you want to do this once, or lots, if once, then BCP would probably be your best, if all the time, the linked servers, or even replication is probably your best bet

Answer (score 1):

in addition to marc_s' answer, you can also [export and import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) data through SSMS' wizard.